# Natural logarithm as "natural" description of fractional change

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation

Suppose the price of a stock is a function of time $p(t)$ and over some period of time $\Delta t = t_1 - t_0$ it changes by some amount $\Delta p = p(t_1)-p(t_0)$.

In class I was told that the natural logarithm represents the fractional change in the stock price, $\frac{\Delta p}{p} = \frac{p(t_1)-p(t_0)}{p(t_0)}$ in the limit as $t_1 \rightarrow t_0$. The justification is that $\frac{d}{dt}ln(p(t))) = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}(p(t))}{p(t)} = \frac{\Delta p}{p}$.

This argument is confusing to me since my understanding is that quantities like $\Delta p$ would actually be represented by $(p(t))' dt$ (a limiting slope times a small step in time) and not the slope itself. This might be an insignificant detail but I've seen these "sensitivity" figures come up in a few contexts and I'd like to know if I'm missing something. Is there a detail I'm missing?

Comment: The problem is illustrated by a share price going from $80$ to $100$ which is a $25\%$ increase calculated from $\frac{100}{80}-1=0.25$, and then going back to $80$ which is a $20\%$ decrease calculated from $\frac{80}{100}-1=-0.2$.  If instead you did $\log_e\left(\frac{100}{80}\right) \approx 0.223$ and $\log_e\left(\frac{80}{100}\right) \approx -0.223$ then you would have two offsetting changes taking you back to the starting point

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your comment, that makes the significance clearer. So then what you're taking the log of is $p(t_1)/p(t_0)$, so the numerator is not a $\Delta p$ but just a $p(t_1)$. When I do a linear approximation of that ratio, I get $p(t_1)/p(t_0) = 1 + (ln(p(t)))'(t_0) (t_1 - t_0)$, so the slope of the function which is the ratio of the price between days is the slope of the natural log of the price function itself evaluated at the first day. Is this correct?